# Grep with multi-threading

Tags: awk, parallel-processing, grep, xargs

I have the following (big) file with 30233088 strings:

`head mystringfile.txt:`

```
GAATGAACACGAAGAA
GAATGAACACGAAGAC
GAATGAACACGAAGAG
GAATGAACACGAAGCA
```

`cat sequence.txt`

```
AAATAGAGGGCGGTCCAGGCGTGTCGAAACACTGGGTCCAGGGCAAGAGCGGTTCGGGTGTCAGGAAAGCCCCCAAGGGGGTTCGCGCGGTTTGCAGTGAGGTAGAGGCCGGTGTATGGGTAGACAATTGGGGTCCCAAAGAAAAAGGCTCGTCCAACATCATAATAAACCCAAGCACGATAAAAAGCAAACGCAGACTTCAATAGGGTACGAGCAATTGTGGCAGGGTGCTCGCTGTCAGGGTTAGATCTTCTTGGAGTCGCGTCGCTCGGGGGGGCAAGGCCAACGTAAGATCGTGGCTGATCGCTGGCAATGCGGTCGGTTGGGTGGTCGCTAGTAGGGGCACGGCGGTCTCTTATGGCGTCGTAAAATGCGTCTCCAAAGCGAAAAGGGGCGGCAGACAAGTCACCGGGCAAGCTTAGAGGTCTGGGGCCCGTGGCTTTAGGGGAATGAACACGAAGACGCGAAACGAAGTCGTGTTTCTTGTTGGCTGTAGAGGGGAAAACCGTCTGGGGCGATCTGGCGTAGTAGTGCGTGTCTTGCAGTGAGCTCCCCGTCCGTAAGGATTCGCAGGAATCCTGCGTGAAGCTCGGTCGTCTCGGCCGTGTCTCGGGGTTTGATTGCGGGTTCAGATTGGAAAGGTCTCCTCGGGTCGTTTGCTGCATTTGCTCGCAACCCTGACGTGAAAGGGGTGAGCTGTCTCCAATCTGCCACGCTGGGTGTTGCGTCGTCAGTAAAAGACTTGGTCAAGCTGGGACCTCGCAAGATCGCGAGAGGGTTAAGCACAAAAGGTATGGCGAAGCTCCCGGGTGCTCTTGTGGCCACCCAGAATCATGGTGACGTAGGTTTTGCGAAGCCATCAAAAATTCAGGCGGCAAAACGAGCCAGTAGGGTCCTGGGCAGCTGGGCTTGTAGTGGGTAGGCGGCAAAACGCAAAGAATGAACACGAAGCAACTCCGTAGTGTGACGGGGGTTCTGACAAACGTCCTGCAAGAAGTTCGTCTTGGG
```

which I need to `grep` in another sequence file to determine the position of the match, which I do as following:

```
while read line; do grep -b -o $line sequence.txt >>sequence.txt.count; done<mystringfile.txt
```

Running the code like this of course takes a very long time and just runs part of 1 thread, so how can I modify it (with `parallel` or `xargs`?) so that it is running on as many threads as I want to specify?

Comment: Could you please share some of that _another sequence file_ for testing?

Comment: please consider my updated question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your idea is wrong with using shell loop to process text. You are opening one new file descriptor for re-directing to output file for each of the 30233088 iterations on your input file. It is prone to a huge performance impact or a case of running out of open file descriptors.

Use the right tool for the job. `Awk` is your friend here. If the `sequence.txt` is just a huge pattern as you say, you can just slurp it into a variable for regex match as below. The solutions involves no memory overhead of having to store entries in RAM

```
awk -v sequence="$(<sequence.txt)" 'n=index(sequence, $1){print n":"$1}' mystringfile.txt
```

This should be relatively faster than the approach you have and to speed up things further, change your `locale` settings to match the `C` local,

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v sequence="$(<sequence.txt)" 'n=index(sequence, $1){print n":"$1}' mystringfile.txt
```

To match with the `grep`'s option of `-b` to print the byte offset start, use `n-1` in the answer above instead of just `n`.

If you still want to use GNU parallel, use `--pipepart` to split the file physically into parts and specify the `--block` size to how much MB of file content to read

```
parallel -a mystringfile.txt --pipepart --block=20M -q awk -v sequence="$(<sequence.txt)" 'n=index(sequence, $1){print n":"$1}'
```

Comment: I added the `-P` flag, great solution!

Comment: @rororo: `-P` flag for? Which solution did you use and how effective was it?

Comment: I used the `parallel` option, it was run on the number of threads I specified via `-P`

Comment: @rororo: So you used my answer or yours with `-P`, how many threads did you specify? How much time did it take? Can you run the command by putting `time` before it and add the result to the question

Comment: However, the solution only works with small sequence files. When using a 2400000 character long sequence file, I get the error `argument list too long`. Sorry, I did not specify that in the initial post

Comment: @rororo You can fix that error by: `$ awk 'NR==FNR{sequence=$1;next}n=index(sequence, $1){print n":"$1}' sequence mystrings`.

Comment: It may be faster using `--block -1` so that `mystringfile.txt` is split evenly into one block per cpu core.

Answer (score 4):

**If all your search strings in** `mystringfile.txt` **are of the same length** (like in your sample file, 16 bytes), you could store all 16 byte strings from `sequence.txt` to an associative array (if you have the memory) and speed up the searching. Let's try that. First we need some test material, let's create a 2400000 byte `sequence.txt`, takes about a second:

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{a[0]="A";a[1]="C";a[2]="G";a[3]="T";srand(seed);for(i=1;i<=2400000;i++)printf "%s", a[int(4*rand())];print ""}' > mystringfile.txt
```

and `mystringfile.txt` with 30233088 16 byte search strings (4 mins 50 secs):

```
$ awk -v seed=$RANDOM 'BEGIN{a[0]="A";a[1]="C";a[2]="G";a[3]="T";srand(seed);for(i=1;i<=30233088;i++){for(j=1;j<=16;j++)printf "%s", a[int(4*rand())];print ""}}' > mystringfile.txt
```

Then the script:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                              # process the sequence file
    l=length($1)-15                    # length-15 16 byte strings coming up
    for(i=1;i<=l;i++) {                # using l as variable name is stupid
        s=substr($0,i,16)              
        a[s]=a[s] (a[s]==""?"":",") i  # hash string start indexes to a, string as key
    }                                  # a["ACTGTGCACGTATAGC"]=3,141,592
    next
}                                      # the search part 
$1 in a {                              # if search string is found
    print a[$1], $1                    # output index and string
}' sequence.txt mystringfile.txt
```

Storing the 2400000 byte `sequence.txt` to the hash took 13 seconds and used 721 MB of memory on my mini laptop. The whole script ran 35 seconds and found around 17000 hits.

Comment: this is ridiculously fast! Thank you!

Comment: @rororo Thanks. That comment goes straight to my CV. :D