# Count overlapping occurrences of a substring *in a very large file* using Bash

Tags: bash

I have files on the order of a few dozen gigabytes (genome data) on which I need to find the number of occurrences for a substring. While the answers I've seen here use `grep -o` then `wc -l`, this seems like a hacky way that might not work for the very large files I need to work with.

Does the `grep -o`/`wc -l` method scale well for large files? If not, how else would I go about doing it?

For example,

```
aaataaaagtcgaaaaagtccatgcatatgatacttttttttttttttttt
111
    222
     333
            444
             555
              666
```

must return 6 occurrences for `aaa`. (Except there are maybe 10 million more lines of this.)

Comment: Have you tried those commands on any of your files yet? Could you please add to your post how long it would take for for a file with what size?

Comment: You probably want to use awk instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222347/grep-with-multi-threading

Comment: @marblewraith I can't load the entire string in memory.

Comment: @WalterA Edited the example to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Find 6 overlapping substrings `aaa` in the string

```
line="aaataaaagtcgaaaaagtccatgcatatgatacttttttttttttttttt"
```

You don't want to see the strings, you want to count them.
When you try

```
# wrong
grep -o -F "aaa" <<< "${line}" | wc -l
```

you are missing the overlapping strings.
With the substring `aaa` you have 5 hits in `aaaaaaa`, so how handle `${line}`?
Start with

```
grep -Eo "a{3,}" <<< "${line}"
```

Result

```
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
```

Hom many hits do we have? 1 for `aaa`, 2 for `aaaa` and 3 for `aaaaa`.
Compare the total count of characters with the number of lines (`wc`):

```
 match lines chars  add_to_total
   aaa     1     4      1
  aaaa     1     5      2
 aaaaa     1     6      3
```

For each line substract 3 from the total count of characters for that line.
When the result has 3 lines and 15 characters, calculate

```
15 characters - (3 lines * 3 characters) = 15 - 9 = 6
```

In code:

```
read -r lines chars < <(grep -Eo "a{3,}" <<< "${line}" | wc -lc)
echo "Substring count: $((chars - (3 * lines)))"
```

Or for a file

```
read -r lines chars < <(grep -Eo "a{3,}" "${file}" | wc -lc)
echo "Substring count: $((chars - (3 * lines)))"
```

`aaa` was "easy", how about other searchstrings?
I think you have to look for the substring and think of a formula that works for that substring. `abcdefghi` will have no overlapping strings, but `abcdabc` might.
Potential matches with `abcdabc` are

```
abcdabc
abcdabcdabc
abcdabcdabcdabc
```

Use testline

```
line="abcdabcdabcdabc something else abcdabcdabcdabc no match here abcdabc and abcdabcdabc"
```

you need `"abc(dabc)+"` and have

```
          match   lines    chars  add_to_total
abcdabcdabcdabc       1      16    3
abcdabcdabcdabc       1      16    3
        abcdabc       1       8    1
    abcdabcdabc       1      12    2
```

For each line substract 4 from the total count of characters and divide the answer by 4. Or `(characters/4) - nr_line`. When the result has 4 lines and 52 characters, calculate

```
(52 characters / fixed 4) / 4 lines = 13 - 4 = 9
```

In code:

```
read -r lines chars < <(grep -Eo "abc(dabc)+" <<< "${line}" | wc -lc)
echo "Substring count: $(( chars / 4 - lines))"
```

When you have a large file, you might want to split it first.

Comment: I was gonna post `grep -Eo 'AAA{1,}' file | wc -lc | awk '{print $1 + $2 - $1 * 4}'` This takes 8 seconds to process a ~1GB (10M rows, 100 cols) file on an *AMD A9-9410 RADEON R5 2C+3G (2) @ 2.900GHz* with GNU grep, GNU wc and GNU awk

Comment: `$1 + $2 - $1 * 4 = $2 - $1 * 3`, so you found the same solution as I did. Nice job, I didn't expect that. You tested the performance, that seems good news for OP. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah, I always sucked at maths

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `read <(grep -o | wc -lc); echo $(( ))`. will it be faster than just `grep -o | awk` ?

Comment: @Fravadona I had no reason for skipping `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are 2 approaches to this (both methods report `29/6` for the 2 test lines):

1. Use the summation method :

   ```
   # WHINY_USERS=1 is a shell param for mawk-1 to pre-sort array

   ${input……} | WHINY_USERS=1 {m,g}awk '
    BEGIN {

    1      FS = "[^a]+(aa?[^a]+)*"
    1      OFS = "|"
    1      PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    } {
    2        _ = ""
    2      OFS = "|"
    2      gsub("^[|]*|[|]*$",_, $!(NF=NF))

    2      split(_,__)
           split($-_,___,"[|]+")

   12      for (_ in ___) {
   12          __[___[_]]++
           }
    2      _____=____=_<_
    2      OFS = "\t"
    2      print " -- line # "(NR)
    7      for (_ in __) {
    7          print sprintf(" %20s",_), __[_], \
                         ______=__[_] * (length(_)-2),\
                     "| "(____+=__[_]), _____+=______
           }
           print "" }'
   ```

|

```
 -- line # 1
                  aaa   3   3   | 3 3
                 aaaa   2   4   | 5 7
                aaaaa   3   9   | 8 16
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa   1   13  | 9 29

 -- line # 2
                  aaa   1   1   | 1 1
                 aaaa   1   2   | 2 3
                aaaaa   1   3   | 3 6
```

2. Print out all the copies of that substring :

   ```
   {m,g}awk' {
   2   printf("%s%.*s",____=$(_=_<_),_, NF=NF)

   9   do { _+=gsub(__,_____)

       } while(index($+__,__))

   2   if(_) {
   2       ____=substr(____,-_<_,_)
   2       gsub(".", (":")__, ____)

   2       print "}-[(# " (_) ")]--;\f\b" substr(____, 2)

      } else { print "" } }' FS='[^a]+(aa?[^a]+)*' OFS='|' __='aaa' _____='aa'
   ```

|

```
aaagtcgaaaaagtccatgcaaataaaagtcgaaaaagtccatgcatatgatactttttttttt
tttttttaaagtcgaaaaagaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatataaaatccatgc}-[(# 29)]--;
                   
         aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:
         aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa

aaataaaagtcgaaaaagtccatgcatatgatacttttttttttttttttt}-[(# 6)]--;
         aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa:aaa
```